# Combination of lists in python?

Tags: python

I am writing a python program which has lists:

```
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C' , 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'X', 'Y', 'Z' ]
digits = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9' ]
```

How can I create a list or something so that my selection statement can identify

```
Identifiers = Letter { Letter | Digit }
Integers  = Digit { Digit }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not completely clear what you want to do. Can you show up what do you expect `Identifiers` and `Integers` to be?

Comment: With a lexer (tokenizer).

Comment: @YilunZhang Identifiers should be a combination of letterletter or letterdigit or just letter and  integer should be a combination of digit or digitdigit

Comment: So, you want to filter incoming strings by Identifiers and Integers? What's your input output like?

Comment: Can you post an expected output

Comment: A suggestion: You could define your letters like this: `import string; letters = list(string.ascii_letters)`. Never underestimate the power of the Python standard library.

Comment: @vash_the_stampede I need to read the characters as a string like Aa or a3 or 12 etc. So suppose if two digits show up together like 11, it should be considered as an integer or if a3 shows up it should be considered as an identifier. Trying to combine letters and digits or digits digits or letters letters.

Answer (score 0):

Python strings have built in checks for letters and digits:

```
   s = "test1"
   for char in s:
       is_digit = char.isdigit()
       is_letter = char.isalpha() or is_digit
       print char, is_letter, is_digit
```

If you are attempting to determine if a character is a letter or digit you should use this.

Answer (score 0):

Since to qualify as an `integer` the entire item must be `ints` we can use `.isdigit()` if item passes this test we can append to `integers` if it fails we can append to `identifiers`

*List comprehension:*

```
identifiers = [i for i in l if not i.isdigit()]
integers = [i for i in l if i.isdigit()]
```

Expanded:

```
l = ['Aa', 'a3', '12']
identifiers = []
integers = []
for i in l:
    if i.isdigit():
        integers.append(i)
    else:
        identifiers.append(i)

print(identifiers)
print(integers)
```

> ```
> ['Aa', 'a3']
> ['12']
> ```